# String Encoding Umlaute

Tags: windows-phone-7, encoding, utf-8, urlencode

I want to send a string with a webclient and i have problems with german umlaute.
Checking with Fiddler, I see that the following conversion for the post parameter is made:

`ä to %E4` (which is iso-8859-1 according to online encoder tool)

Do you know how i can achive this for WP7?

I tried already:

- `string urlstring = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ä");`

  RESULT: `%c3%a4`
- `string urlstring1 = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("ä");`

  RESULT: `ä`
- `Encoding isoenc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");`
  `byte[] utf8characters = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ä");`
  `byte[] isoArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),utf8characters);`
   `string finalString = isoenc.GetString(isoArray,0, isoArray.Length);`

  RESULT: `ä`

I also checked this silverlight tool where you can create custom encoding.. without success.

I'm getting really crazy about this issue, if anyone has an idea please let me know.

Thanks, 
 Ralf

Comment: That's an interesting question. You can retrieve the E4 by doing: `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes("ä")[0].ToString("X")` From there, maybe make you custom string encoder that checks bytes greater than 127, and replaces them by their encoded value? Also, is it really needed to send `%E4`? The issue may just be that the value you're sending to the server isn't encoded in iso-8859-1 to begin with

Comment: so i checked again without encoding: i send a string incl. "ä" request will be rejected, i send a string incl. "%E4" it's accepeted from teh server and shows "ä".

Comment: so i checked again without encoding: i send a string incl. "ä" request will be rejected; i send a string incl. "%E4" it's accepted from the server and shows "ä", when is send "%c3%a4" (standard HttpUtility.Encoding) it shows "Ã„" (btw. i also tried with webclient.encoding iso-8859-1,  but this will not work because the string has multiple parameter (with =), webclient.encoding utf8 is fine, and is also shown in Fiddler when i make a post through webpage) But the method you mentioned is an interesting approach, i will investigate on this. Thx :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided by nwellnhof is good, but the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` overload that takes an encoding as parameter isn't available on Windows Phone. Fortunately, by decompiling the framework assemblies, it's easy to modify it to use the encoding you want:

```
public class HttpUtilityEx
{
    public static string UrlEncode(string url, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (url == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(url);
        int num = 0;
        int num1 = 0;
        int length = (int)bytes.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char chr = (char)bytes[i];
            if (chr == ' ')
            {
                num++;
            }
            else if (!IsSafe(chr))
            {
                num1++;
            }
        }
        if ((num != 0 ? true : num1 != 0))
        {
            byte[] hex = new byte[length + num1 * 2];
            int num2 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                byte num3 = bytes[j];
                char chr1 = (char)num3;
                if (IsSafe(chr1))
                {
                    int num4 = num2;
                    num2 = num4 + 1;
                    hex[num4] = num3;
                }
                else if (chr1 != ' ')
                {
                    int num5 = num2;
                    num2 = num5 + 1;
                    hex[num5] = 37;
                    int num6 = num2;
                    num2 = num6 + 1;
                    hex[num6] = (byte)IntToHex(num3 >> 4 & 15);
                    int num7 = num2;
                    num2 = num7 + 1;
                    hex[num7] = (byte)IntToHex(num3 & 15);
                }
                else
                {
                    int num8 = num2;
                    num2 = num8 + 1;
                    hex[num8] = 43;
                }
            }
            bytes = hex;
        }
        return encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
    }

    private static bool IsSafe(char ch)
    {
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            return true;
        }
        char chr = ch;
        if (chr != '!')
        {
            switch (chr)
            {
                case '\'':
                case '(':
                case ')':
                case '*':
                case '-':
                case '.':
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                case '+':
                case ',':
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        if (chr != '\u005F')
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    internal static char IntToHex(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 9)
        {
            return (char)(n + 48);
        }
        return (char)(n - 10 + 97);
    }
}
```

From there, you just need to call it like you would for HttpUtility:

```
var result = HttpUtilityEx.UrlEncode("ä", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for. You saved my day. Many thanks :-) ... and i have bookmarked your blog now.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` has an [optional second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode.aspx) which specifies the encoding. The following should work:

```
Encoding isoenc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
String urlstring = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ä", isoenc);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this overload isn't available on Windows Phone